# NSSearchField results menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I've been searching for hours and still haven't found an answer to this. How can you get an `NSSearchField` to display a menu with results. I can use the recent searches menu to display results, but how do I make the menu display programmatically? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Apple does this with some private methods. Maybe it uses an `NSWindow` instead of an `NSMenu`. One way to do it is to implement this in your `NSSearchField` delegate assuming you have an `IBOutlet` pointing to the `NSSearchField`.

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing: (NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *searchString = [searchField stringValue];

    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle: @"results"];

    [menu addItemWithTitle: searchString action: @selector(someAction:) keyEquivalent: @""];
    [menu addItemWithTitle: @"someString" action: @selector(someOtherAction:) keyEquivalent: @""];

    NSEvent *event =  [NSEvent otherEventWithType: NSApplicationDefined
                                         location: [searchField frame].origin
                                    modifierFlags: 0
                                        timestamp: 0
                                     windowNumber: [[searchField window] windowNumber]
                                          context: [[searchField window] graphicsContext]
                                          subtype: NSApplicationDefined
                                            data1: 0
                                            data2: 0];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu: [menu autorelease] withEvent: event forView: searchField];
}
```

Note that showing a menu prevents further typing in the `NSSearchField`. That's why I used `controlTextDidEndEditing:`and not `controlTextDidChange:`. You should also check [NSEvent's Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more customization of the event.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. The only change was that I modified the location parameter in the event to shift the menu down by about 5 so that it doesn't overlap the search field. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested this but maybe you could change the whole NSEvent thing to `[NSEvent currentEvent]`. Perhaps then it gets the default location etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has [some sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html) code similar to what you need. The sample code uses NSTextField (which is a parent class of NSSearchField). Hopefully, this solves your problem.